# Bootstrap 3: tabs à esquerda não funcionam mais?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3

Olá, este código a seguir não funciona mais no Bootstrap 3?

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  ...
 </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  ...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No seu ul, você pode adicionar duas classes que acredito que resolvem seu problema, faça um teste: `<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked pull-left" data-tabs="tabs">`, no caso adicionei `nav-stacked`que empilhará elas, e `pull-left` que as jogará para esquerda. Caso queira para a direita, é só mudar o `pull-left` para `pull-right`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não, esses componentes foram retirados na versão 3.0;
Mas você pode ter um resultado similar de duas maneiras diferentes:

## 1 - Adicionando seu próprio estilo ao CSS:

```
/* custom inclusion of right, left and below tabs */

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
          border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
          border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 19px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
```

exemplo: http://www.bootply.com/TwKP42WfaP

## 2 - Optar pelo componente `nav-pills`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Tabulação com pills</h3>
            <!-- tabs left -->
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-3">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">Um</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">Dois</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab">Três</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content col-md-9">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius rci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="c">Thirdamuno, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Duis pharetra
                    varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae. </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabs -->
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Exemplo: http://www.bootply.com/Ij4g6wHGcQ

Comment: Muito obrigado!